# How to preserve SVG background and widget alignment during resizing?

Tags: c++, qt, svg, background, resize

I am working on a Qt desktop application where I want to have an SVG as the background. The widgets in the UI should remain in their positions relative to the SVG coordinates when the window is resized.

I've managed to load the SVG and the UI using `QUiLoader` and set the SVG as the background.

However, when I resize the window, the widgets don't maintain their positions relative to the SVG background.

How can I ensure that the widgets and the SVG scale together and maintain their relative positions when the window is resized?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```cpp
QGraphicsSvgItem *svgItem = new QGraphicsSvgItem(":/vectorised-color2.svg");
scene->addItem(svgItem);
view->setScene(scene);
setCentralWidget(view);

QFile file(":/view.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

QUiLoader loader;
QWidget *widget = loader.load(&file, this);
// ... add widget to scene

widget->resize(svgBounds.width(), svgBounds.height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the same *`.ui`* file via `QUILoader` does the trick, scaling the UI with the SVG. I am not sure why. If you load a separate *`.ui`* file, this does not seem to work.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSvgItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QtUiTools/QUiLoader>
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "resizinggraphicsview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QWidget *spacer = new QWidget(this);
    spacer->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    ui->toolBar->addWidget(spacer);
    ui->toolBar->addAction(ui->actionAbout);

    ResizingGraphicsView *view = new ResizingGraphicsView(this);
    view->setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
    view->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsSvgItem *svgItem = new QGraphicsSvgItem(":/vectorised-color2.svg");

    scene->addItem(svgItem);
    view->setScene(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);

    QFile file(":/mainwindow.ui");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    QUiLoader loader;
    QWidget *widget = loader.load(&file, this);

    removeToolbarAndStatusBar(widget);
    QRectF svgBounds = svgItem->boundingRect();
    widget->resize(svgBounds.width(), svgBounds.height());
    file.close();
    widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = scene->addWidget(widget);
    proxy->setAutoFillBackground(false);

    // signals need to be explicitly connected
    QPushButton *pushButton = widget->findChild<QPushButton *>("pushButton");
    if (pushButton) {
        connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::clickbutton);
    }
}

/*
 * This is a hack: For some reason by loading the SAME .ui file (mainwindow),
 * widgets resize in sync while keeping the svg image centered
 * But without this we would get duplicated toolbar and statusbar
 * */

void MainWindow::removeToolbarAndStatusBar(QWidget *widget)
{
    QToolBar *toolbar = widget->findChild<QToolBar *>("toolBar");
    if (toolbar) {
        toolbar->hide(); // or delete toolbar;
    }
    QStatusBar *statusBar = widget->findChild<QStatusBar *>("statusbar");
    if (statusBar) {
        statusBar->hide(); // or delete statusBar;
    }
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::clickbutton()
{
    qDebug() << "button click";
}
```

**Notes:**

- If you have a toolbar or a statusbar, you need to hide them manually.
- You need to connect signals from the UI widgets manually.